# How to send SwftyJSON with Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, alamofire, swifty-json

I have long data that I want send to API server with alamofire so I created a Json object with SwiftyJSON and now if I pass the json to alamofire it gives an error please explain what I am missing ?

**Json :**

```
{
  "Skill" : {
    "Name" : "iOS",
    "Desc" : "Objective-C, Swift"
  },
  "LangInfo" : [
    "Hindi",
    "English",
    "French",
    "Russian"
  ],
  "EduInfo" : {
    "Degree" : "MCA",
    "School" : "University of Kota",
    "Year" : "2013"
  },
  "GenInfo" : {
    "FirstName" : "Varun",
    "Email" : "varun@gmail.com",
    "State" : "Rajasthan",
    "Address" : "Plot No. 00, Bhagwan Nagar 31,",
    "Zip" : "21354",
    "Phone" : "123456789",
    "LastName" : "Sharma"
  }
}
```

**Code :-**

```
var jsonObj = JSON(skilldata.data)
        println(jsonObj);

        let parameters = [
            "data": jsonObj
        ]
        Alamofire.request(.POST, BaseUrl+SaveData, parameters: parameters)
            .responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) in
                println(JSON)
                let dict:Dictionary<String, String> = JSON as! Dictionary<String, String>
                println(dict["status"])
        }
```

Here `skilldata.data` is  `var data = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()`

and the error is on the line `.responseJSON { (_, _, JSON, _) in` [image: Error]

**Edit #1**
[image: Code with Error]

**Edit #2**
Xcode ver :- 6.2.3

and

Using pod for Alamofire and SwiftyJson

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
```

Comment: This code works fine in the Alamofire playground. Are you sure that's your actual `responseJSON` block?

Comment: yes, I just copy paste the code

Comment: Are you using an old version of Swift, Xcode, or Alamofire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type `JSON` does not conform to any object protocol so you will need to get object from `jsonObj`. After getting object parameters type will be `[String : AnyObject]` and only after that, it will meet parameter type of Alamofire request

```
let parameters = [
        "data": jsonObj.object
    ]
```

Comment: one more thing am I sending the json in right format will I am able to receive the whole json in `$data= $_POST["data"];` ???

Comment: this will work but the json will not longer be a JSON.